# check if two strings have similar characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

i have a database model that accepts "first_name" but I want it to accept different versions of the word first name. A user might try to save it by choosing to enter it this way "first name" or "first name " (notice the white space between them). I want it to convert to "first_name" so it can be saved in the model

Comment: `" first   name  ".strip.gsub(/\s+/,"_")` the `strip` method removes leading and trailing whitespace, and the gsub regex replaces any number of whitespace characters between the words with a single underscore. Is this what you want? It matches your question but not the title of your post!

Comment: this is what i want. you are spot on

Comment: What if user submit `FirSt name`? Is it the same as `first_name`?

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 7.1+ you can use [`ActiveRecord::Normalization::normalizes`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Normalization/ClassMethods.html) such way:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  normalizes :name, with: ->(name) { name.downcase.strip.gsub(/\s+/, "_") }
end
```

Normalization runs before validation and doesn't apply to `nil` by default (that's why it's safe)

It works seamlessly with both persistence and finder methods

```rb
user = User.create(name: " first   name  ")
user.name # => "first_name"

user = User.find_by(name: " first   name  ")
user.name # => "first_name"
```

To normalize legacy records with [`ActiveRecord::Normalization#normalize_attribute`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Normalization.html):

```rb
User.find_each do |user|
  user.normalize_attribute(:name)
  user.save! # solve constraints and validations issues manually
end
```

Comment: i think this is also helpful